# DRM - how to protect license URL on mobile app

Tags: mobile, exoplayer, drm

I see a lot of info regarding DRM itself on internet, but did no find info on how to protect license URL itself. To play DRM on e.g. exoplayer on mobile I need DASH url and license URL, but if one can manage to get those from the code then he can play video anywhere anytime. How do I protect those?

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to protect the license acquisition URL - this is included in the content manifest and headers itself for some DRM's including PlayReady.

The LA URL is simply the address that the client sends the license request to.

The license request itself has in the body of the request data about the client and can include encrypted custom authentication tokens etc.

For completeness, looking at the license server response, if the license server determines that the user is a valid user, it will send the response with the decryption license itself encrypted so that only the device making the request can decrypt it - i.e. if someone else were to intercept the response it would not work on a different device, as each device has a unique DRM instance on it.

Microsoft provide some really useful overviews of the end to end flows for PlayReady including sample request bodies and response bodies online (at the time of writing) - these are an excellent place to understand how a DRM works:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/playready/overview/license-server